# RichEditor - Filament Image upload not working

Tags: php

**Here "body" is column name , the image added in rich editor is not stored**

```
 RichEditor::make('body')
            ->fileAttachmentsDisk('s3')
            ->fileAttachmentsDirectory('attachments')
            ->fileAttachmentsVisibility('public')
            ->columnSpan(2)
            ->required(),
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.answeroverflow.com/m/1203416479001747476, you may have missed the actual configuration.

Comment: The image is not storing in database ,as it saves in MarkdownEditor , i cange the filesystem , rechecked the env, 
Any image uploaded via FileUpload::make  method its showing , but rich editor images added in body are not storing in database

RichEditor::make('body')
                    ->fileAttachmentsDisk('s3')
                    ->fileAttachmentsDirectory('attachments')
                    ->fileAttachmentsVisibility('private')
                    ->columnSpan(2)
                    ->required(),

Answer (score 0):

Alternate Editor we use to acheive same functionality

```
Forms\Components\MarkdownEditor::make('body')
                ->required()
                ->columnSpan('full'),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is here for RichText Editor Filament**
Just add
**RichEditor::make('body'),**
Where body is column name.
Dont need to add these, this apply restriction to RichText Editor, which make failure to add image in content body

```
->fileAttachmentsDisk('s3')
            ->fileAttachmentsDirectory('attachments')
            ->fileAttachmentsVisibility('public')
            ->columnSpan(2)
            ->required(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly you can also use below mentioned editor ,

composer require mohamedsabil83/filament-forms-tinyeditor

php artisan vendor:publish --tag="filament-forms-tinyeditor-config"

TinyEditor::make('body'),